# pepare-commit-msg is not been executed

Tags: git

I have successfully added a commit.template file .git-commit-message.
Git seems that it uses this file to generate the commit file.
I now want to add the branch name in the file so in the

```
prepare-commit-msg
git symbolic-ref HEAD >> .git-commit-message
```

The problem is that this hook is not been executed.
Does git have some kind of config to define which hooks will be executed?

I have run git init
the file's permissions are as follows

```
ls -al .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1
```

Comment: Is the file in `.git/hooks/`? Is it executable? Can you run it manually from the root of the repository and get the expected `.git-commit-message` in the root?

Comment: Yes it's on .git/hooks/ and I can run it manually